# how to send custon xmpp/jabber requests to a server

Tags: xml, command-line, xmpp, chat

I wish to send custom built xmpp/jabber requests to a chat server. The Jabber XML content looks like:

```
<message from='foo@bar.abc/def' to='def@ghi/jkl' xml:lang='' id='xyz' type='groupchat'>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</message>
```

How do I send other custom messages if I wish to change the values of "foo", "def" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way.

Using Pidgin and its XMPP Console it is pretty easy to send any custom built xmpp messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use Telnet!

```
telnet chat.facebook.com 522
```

Then send your XML.